# Any other alternative to upload files to Drive without using service account keys

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

Context:
I have a script which uploads zip files to Drive using python and Drive api. In order to use Drive API I'm using client-secret.json key. because of internal changes I need to stop using service account keys. Is there any other alternate way to use Drive API using normal account instead of service account?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with a desktop credential instead of a service account.

You can check the [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) under prerequisites you will see:

> Authorization credentials for a desktop application. To learn how to create credentials for a desktop application, refer to [Create credentials](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials).

Then you will need to change the way you authorize the credentials on the script. You can use the quickstart ones as well:

```py
creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```